# How to put GeoJSON coordinates to TIFF?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I have GeoJSON coord:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
 "features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
   [[[66.87480926513672,48.111213657240576],
   [66.89043045043945,48.111213657240576],
   [66.89043045043945,48.119751843350834],
   [66.87480926513672,48.119751843350834],
   [66.87480926513672,48.111213657240576]
]]}}]}
```

And I have image from satelite of this area in PNG format:

How can I connect coords and image in one TIFF/GeoTIFF file?

I tried this solution [Georeferencing raster using GDAL and Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116672/georeferencing-raster-using-gdal-and-python), but I cannot understand how to convert my coord to this format:

```
gt = [-7916400, 100, 0, 5210940, 0, -100]
```

Answer (score 2):

The polygon seems to be a north-up oriented rectangle so you can simply assign the upper-left and lower-right coordinates into the image.

With Python you can then use
https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Translate
and use the options as documented in
https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions

You can test the conversion with the gdal_translate utility
https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#gdal-translate

Usage:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -ullr 66.87480926513672 48.119751843350834 66.89043045043945 48.111213657240576 input.png output.tif
```

The coordinate system of the polygon is probably EPSG:4326 and you can assign that with `-a_srs epsg:4326`. However, the png that you have may actually use some other crs like EPSG:3857. In this case some additional steps are needed.

Answer (score 1):

In [Georeferencing raster using GDAL and Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116672/georeferencing-raster-using-gdal-and-python)

```
# Specify raster location through geotransform array
# (uperleftx, scalex, skewx, uperlefty, skewy, scaley)
# Scale = size of one pixel in units of raster projection
# this example below assumes 100x100
gt = [-7916400, 100, 0, 5210940, 0, -100]
```

You can use the script of Ian Turton in [Convert GeoJSON object to bounding box using Python 3.6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313023/2581), the library 
[geojson-bbox](https://github.com/Luqqk/geojson-bbox) and others.

```
import gbbox #geojson-bbox
pol = {"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
[[[66.87480926513672,48.111213657240576],
[66.89043045043945,48.111213657240576],
[66.89043045043945,48.119751843350834],
[66.87480926513672,48.119751843350834],
[66.87480926513672,48.111213657240576]
]]}}]}
min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y =  gbbox.GeoJSON(pol).bbox()
print( min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y)
66.87480926513672 48.111213657240576 66.89043045043945 48.119751843350834
```

And you get uperleftx (min_x), and uperlefty (max_y). Assuming 100x100 as in [Georeferencing raster using GDAL and Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116672/georeferencing-raster-using-gdal-and-python)

```
 gt = [66.87480926513672 , 100, 0, 48.119751843350834, 0, -100]
```

But in reality  you need the size of the raster (width, height) to compute the real size of the pixel

Comment: Look at [Transforming a image to a shape defined by image corners in earth coordinates - Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/325268/2581)